# Get type text/html instead of javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, tomcat, redis

I have the following line on my jsp page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=contextpath%>/dummyapp/myscript.js"></script>
```

but for some reason, this part return 302 and a type as text/html, when I investigate it from the chrome dev, why this happens?

I have REDIS + tomcat , jsp pages

Comment: 302 is not modified. Can you do a hard reload of your page and inspect it then

Comment: I press F5 and then check Network, and I see 302, but the script is in place...

Comment: F5 is not the correct way, long press  round arrow to the left of your address bar and select hard reload from the drop down

Comment: tried, and the resul is the same

Comment: the type that you are seeing is of whole page content , if I am not wrong, rather this particular content. That might be the case

Comment: tjis worked fine before i added redis

Comment: the same issue with css, seems like it loading css, and then somehow css iniciates to load index.jsp and then it return 404

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: Your JSP tag is missing the opening bracket.

Comment: `src="%=contextpath%>/dummyapp/myscript.js">` should be  `src="<%=contextpath%>/dummyapp/myscript.js"> `

Comment: yes, i know, i was modifying it manually , did not want to put the whole real path, this is not a problem, I have it correctly in my sources